# Postgresql infinite loop after a hibernate criteria list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm stucked with a database problem for several days now. The application hangs after a specific hibernate criteria.list(). Exactly by the following stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)
org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(int)
org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(int)
org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read()
org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar()
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(ResultHandler, int)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(Query, ParameterList, ResultHandler, int, int, int)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(Query, ParameterList, int)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(int)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery()
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list()
```

After some researches and tests I found that the problem is not a blocking query, but a query that is executed forever.

It's a java spring application with the following sessionFactory and transaction manager configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp.domain" /> 
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

The underlying database is PostgreSQL and here is the current hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>       
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="order_updates">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The critical area in the code is:

```
private void fillEmptyNames() throws CablewatchException {
    List<Device> devicesList = deviceDao.getDevices();
    if (devicesList != null) {
        for (Device device : devicesList {
            String name = deviceDao.getDeviceName(device.getModule().getObjectIdentifier(), device.getSubrack(), device.getSlot());
    ...
        }
    }
}
```

The application hangs on the second dao function "getDeviceName". which is implemented as follow:

```
@Transactional(timeout=30)
public String getDeviceName(long moduleId, int subrackNr, int slotNr) throws CablewatchException {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class).add(Restrictions.eq("module.objectIdentifier", moduleId)).add(Restrictions.eq("subrack",subrackNr)).add(Restrictions.eq("slot",slotNr)).addOrder(Order.desc("objectIdentifier")).setMaxResults(1);

    List<Device> devicesList = criteria.list();

    if (devicesList != null && !devicesList.isEmpty() && devicesList.get(0) instanceof Device) {
        Device device = devicesList.get(0);
        return device.getName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also a detail I'm confronted with is that the same passage works fine under Windows, so currently the problem is only happening on Linux.

UPDATE:
The generated query is:

```
select
    this_.objectIdentifier as objectId1_0_9_,
    this_.ackId as ackId11_0_9_,
    this_.alarmInfoId as alarmIn12_0_9_,
    this_.cleared as cleared2_0_9_,
    this_.clearedTime as clearedT3_0_9_,
    this_.logIndex as logIndex4_0_9_,
    this_.module as module5_0_9_,
    this_.neId as neId13_0_9_,
    this_.occurenceTime as occurenc6_0_9_,
    this_.serial as serial7_0_9_,
    this_.severityId as severit14_0_9_,
    this_.slot as slot8_0_9_,
    this_.subrack as subrack9_0_9_,
    this_.value as value10_0_9_,
    acknowledg2_.objectIdentifier as objectId1_2_0_,
    acknowledg2_.comment as comment2_2_0_,
    acknowledg2_.username as username3_2_0_,
    alarminfo3_.objectIdentifier as objectId1_1_1_,
    alarminfo3_.cw_alarmMessage as cw_alarm2_1_1_,
    alarminfo3_.cw_alarmOid as cw_alarm3_1_1_,
    ne4_.OBJECTIDENTIFIER as OBJECTID1_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neActive as cw_neAct2_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neCategory as cw_neCat3_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neFirmware as cw_neFir4_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neHasWebInterface as cw_neHas5_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neInetAddress as cw_neIne6_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neInfo as cw_neInf7_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neMacAddress as cw_neMac8_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neModel as cw_neMod9_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neName as cw_neNa10_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neSerial as cw_neSe11_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neSysDescription as cw_neSy12_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_neType as cw_neTy13_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_installationDate as cw_inst14_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_instance as cw_inst15_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_lastAlarmLogIndex as cw_last16_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_locationId as cw_loca19_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_readCommunity as cw_read17_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_severityId as cw_seve20_8_2_,
    ne4_.cw_writeCommunity as cw_writ18_8_2_,
    location5_.objectIdentifier as objectId1_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_imageName as cw_image2_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationCity as cw_locat3_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationCode as cw_locat4_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationContact as cw_locat5_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationDescription1 as cw_locat6_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationDescription2 as cw_locat7_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationName as cw_locat8_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationStreet as cw_locat9_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_locationType as cw_loca10_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_parentLocationId as cw_pare11_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_severityId as cw_seve12_5_3_,
    location5_.cw_sublocationSeverityId as cw_subl13_5_3_,
    location6_.objectIdentifier as objectId1_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_imageName as cw_image2_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationCity as cw_locat3_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationCode as cw_locat4_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationContact as cw_locat5_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationDescription1 as cw_locat6_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationDescription2 as cw_locat7_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationName as cw_locat8_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationStreet as cw_locat9_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_locationType as cw_loca10_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_parentLocationId as cw_pare11_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_severityId as cw_seve12_5_4_,
    location6_.cw_sublocationSeverityId as cw_subl13_5_4_,
    severity7_.id as id1_15_5_,
    severity7_.cw_severityColor as cw_sever2_15_5_,
    severity7_.cw_severityName as cw_sever3_15_5_,
    severity8_.id as id1_15_6_,
    severity8_.cw_severityColor as cw_sever2_15_6_,
    severity8_.cw_severityName as cw_sever3_15_6_,
    severity9_.id as id1_15_7_,
    severity9_.cw_severityColor as cw_sever2_15_7_,
    severity9_.cw_severityName as cw_sever3_15_7_,
    severity10_.id as id1_15_8_,
    severity10_.cw_severityColor as cw_sever2_15_8_,
    severity10_.cw_severityName as cw_sever3_15_8_ 
from
    CW_ALARM this_ 
left outer join
    CW_Acknowledgment acknowledg2_ 
        on this_.ackId=acknowledg2_.objectIdentifier 
left outer join
    CW_ALARMINFO alarminfo3_ 
        on this_.alarmInfoId=alarminfo3_.objectIdentifier 
left outer join
    CW_NE ne4_ 
        on this_.neId=ne4_.OBJECTIDENTIFIER 
left outer join
    CW_LOCATION location5_ 
        on ne4_.cw_locationId=location5_.objectIdentifier 
left outer join
    CW_LOCATION location6_ 
        on location5_.cw_parentLocationId=location6_.objectIdentifier 
left outer join
    CW_SEVERITY severity7_ 
        on location6_.cw_severityId=severity7_.id 
left outer join
    CW_SEVERITY severity8_ 
        on location6_.cw_sublocationSeverityId=severity8_.id 
left outer join
    CW_SEVERITY severity9_ 
        on ne4_.cw_severityId=severity9_.id 
left outer join
    CW_SEVERITY severity10_ 
        on this_.severityId=severity10_.id 
where
    this_.neId=?
    and this_.subrack=?
    and this_.slot=?
    and this_.module<>?
order by
    this_.objectIdentifier desc limit ?
```

I executed it from pgAdmin (and replaced the parameters with their values) and it works fine. Below is the query plan:

```
"Limit  (cost=25819.66..25819.66 rows=1 width=1185)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=25819.66..25819.66 rows=1 width=1185)"
"        Sort Key: this_.objectidentifier"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25819.65 rows=1 width=1185)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25811.37 rows=1 width=1021)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25803.09 rows=1 width=857)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25799.21 rows=1 width=693)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25795.33 rows=1 width=529)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25793.45 rows=1 width=464)"
"                                            Join Filter: (ne4_.cw_locationid = location5_.objectidentifier)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25791.22 rows=1 width=399)"
"                                                  Join Filter: (this_.neid = ne4_.objectidentifier)"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25788.76 rows=1 width=225)"
"                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..25780.48 rows=1 width=150)"
"                                                              Join Filter: (this_.ackid = acknowledg2_.objectidentifier)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on cw_alarm this_  (cost=0.00..25779.32 rows=1 width=132)"
"                                                                    Filter: (((module)::text <> ''::text) AND (neid = 471) AND (subrack = (-1)) AND (slot = (-1)))"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on cw_acknowledgment acknowledg2_  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=7 width=18)"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using cw_alarminfo_pkey on cw_alarminfo alarminfo3_  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=75)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (this_.alarminfoid = objectidentifier)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on cw_ne ne4_  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=1 width=174)"
"                                                        Filter: (objectidentifier = 471)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on cw_location location5_  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=10 width=65)"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using cw_location_pkey on cw_location location6_  (cost=0.00..1.87 rows=1 width=65)"
"                                            Index Cond: (location5_.cw_parentlocationid = objectidentifier)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using cw_severity_pkey on cw_severity severity7_  (cost=0.00..3.87 rows=1 width=164)"
"                                      Index Cond: (location6_.cw_severityid = id)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using cw_severity_pkey on cw_severity severity8_  (cost=0.00..3.87 rows=1 width=164)"
"                                Index Cond: (location6_.cw_sublocationseverityid = id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using cw_severity_pkey on cw_severity severity9_  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=164)"
"                          Index Cond: (ne4_.cw_severityid = id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using cw_severity_pkey on cw_severity severity10_  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=164)"
"                    Index Cond: (this_.severityid = id)"
```

Following the detail about Linux and Windows version, I've tried the same test but instead of the local database postgresql_9.1.13 (Debian) I used a remote access to postgresql_9.3.5(Windows) and installed and tried postgresql_9.1.13(Windows). Both worked correctly.

I also tried the same code from my Windows system to the remote postgresql_9.1.13(Debian) and another machine with a remote postgresql_9.1.15(Debian). In both cases the problem occurs.

It seems the problem could lay on the Linux version of postgresql_9.1.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what's the actual SQL that's getting run? Get it from the `pg_stat_activity` view or by enabling query logging in Hibernate. Edit your question to show the query, then comment here when done. Also please re-run your query in `psql` or PgAdmin3 with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and paste the query plan here too.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the advice. I've updated the question.

Comment: Is there any CPU load on the postgres side? Does `pg_locks` show any locks?

Comment: What a ghastly query. ORMs that do huge chained left joins to fetch data and de-duplicate it client side like this are just ugly. I wish they'd at least just fetch id-lists and then batch-retrieve the object data.

Comment: I wouldn't think platform is a major factor. Locking issues are more likely, or issues with plan choice and statistics. On one of the ones that work fine, please do an `explain analyze select ...` of your query and again update here. Also check `pg_stat_activity` for the apparently stuck query to see if `waiting = t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the database with the commands Craig and Clemens provided me (display current queries, pg_stat_activity, explain analyze select, pg_locks etc.), I found out that it isn't an infinite loop but due to an access for more than 20.000 entries the running time was very long. And due to the ORM layer this time was even extended to exceed several hours. I'm working on a small redesign of the database to optimize this issue.

Thanks guys for the support.